# MDM JavaPNS - Convert Device Token to Hexa value. (32 byte binary value to 64 char Hex value)

Tags: ios, enterprise, apple-push-notifications, mdm, devicetoken

I'm working on iOS MDM. During enrollment i got deviceToken, PushMagic and unlockToken.
Plan to use [javapns](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/). It expect 64 hex value.

This is my original Device Token format. It is 32 byte binary value and base64 encoded.

> 54CC9f18PLXag/RgOCtc30o7lC3beG6NruUSE0/vCC0=

Do i need to convert the above format to send notification to APNs via javapns.
If so how to convert encoded device token to 64 char hexadecimal.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Vinothkumar.R

Answer (score 2):

C# answer:

byte[] deviceToken = Convert.FromBase64String( "54CC9f18PLXag/RgOCtc30o7lC3beG6NruUSE0/vCC0=" );

then send the deviceToken binar byte[] to apple after the big endian length.

Answer (score 2):

Java, you try:

```
String token = "j9KAZ7nka3wwAfjCpONXrpAzxRP1vPMBl/x5CTCfKYI=";
byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(token.getBytes());
System.out.println("DeviceToken: " + Hex.encodeHexString(bytes));
```

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJs use

```
    var originalDeviceToken = '54CC9f18PLXag/RgOCtc30o7lC3beG6NruUSE0/vCC0=';
    var b = new Buffer(originalDeviceToken, 'base64')
    var hexToken = b.toString('hex');
```